# How to post (HTTP POST) zipfile and parameters in ObjectiveC?

Tags: iphone, web-services, file-upload, http-post, zip

I have tried to Post a Zipfile and some parameters to web service, but i get the response "missing ebook file", so how to Post zip file and parameters in Objectivec please help me

Thanks in Advance

I have tried this:

```
      NSString *urlString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.EbookFile.com/index.php?q=api/upload&APPkey=dfsfwerwe324342323432"];



    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
                [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString1]];
                [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

                    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
                    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
                    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
                    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

                // Parameter 1

                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uid\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[uid dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


                        // Parameter 2

                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[titleText.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                // Parameter 3


                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"token\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[token dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                // Parameter 4


                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"desc\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[descText.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                // Parameter 5


                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"cat\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[CatId dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


        // ZIP File Post here

                int r = arc4random() % 8000000;
                NSString *RandomNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",r];
                NSString *file = [RandomNumber stringByAppendingString:@".zip"];

                NSData *Filedata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:archivePath]]; // ZIP file convert to NAData here

                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",file] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:Filedata];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [request setHTTPBody:body];

                // pointers to some necessary objects
                NSHTTPURLResponse* response =[[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] init];
                NSError* error = [[NSError alloc] init] ;

                // synchronous filling of data from HTTP POST response
                NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

                if (error)
                {
                }

 NSString *responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[responseData bytes]
                                                                     length:[responseData length]
                                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 NSString *urlString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.efferwrwre.com/index.php?q=api/upload&key=f5746442fb9067b3fba83c3da0351f1f"];
    NSLog(@"URLSTribg : %@", urlString1);
    NSString *ww = [urlString1 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ww]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    
    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
        
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uid\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[uid dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    
    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[titleText.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    
    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"token\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[token dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    
    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"desc\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[descText.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"cat\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[CatId dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    
    int r = arc4random() % 8000000;
    NSString *RandomNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",r];
    NSString *file = [RandomNumber stringByAppendingString:@".zip"];
    
    NSData *Filedata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:archivePath]];
    NSLog(@"file:%@",Filedata);
    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",file] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:Filedata];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

 NSHTTPURLResponse* response =[[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] init];
    NSError* error = [[NSError alloc] init] ;
    
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        
    }
    
    NSString *responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[responseData bytes]
                                                         length:[responseData length]
                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Send the file your file in this way

```
    NSUInteger length = [myData length];
    NSData *filedata;
         Byte *byteData = (Byte *)malloc(length);
        [data getBytes:byteData length:length];


       [postbody appendBytes:(const void *)byteData length:length];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there are different styles of web services, and you haven't specified which you're dealing with. Is it a SOAP-based service? REST? XML-RPC? For the sake of discussion, I'll assume it's a RESTful service, since that's where most people seem to be going these days.

The problem I see is that you're trying to put the parameters in the body of the post. You'll have to check the documentation for the specific API that you're using, but usually parameters are provided either as query parameters in the URL that you're posting to, or specified in the headers that you send in the request. The body of the request should be the zipped data.